# linq update problem with linq to enitites

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

Hi i have table called products...with columns

```
             product_id  (p.K)
             product_name
             product_description
             product_price
             category_id  (F.k)
```

i have another table category

```
                   category_id  (p.k)
                   category_name
```

what i have tried is i am trying to update the product table with category_id got the problem
 i have got the following code....

```
         Private void btnsave_click(object sender , eventargs e)
         {

                 if (datagridview1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
                 {
                     int updateproductid = Convert.ToInt32(datagridview1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);

                     string productcategories =cbCategorytypes.Text;

                     var categorytypes = (from producttype in dbcontext.categories
                                          where producttype.name.Equals(productcategories)
                                          select producttype.categoryId).SingleOrDefault();

                     product product1 = new product() { productId = updateproductid };
                     dbcontext.products.Attach(product1);
                     product1.Name = txtProductname.Text;
                     product1.Description = txtProductdescription.Text;
                     product1.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtProductPrice.Text);
                     product1.categoryId = categorytypes;
                     dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                 }

         }
```

**got an error :**   **Invalid Operation Exception Was Unhandled**  : An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

would any one pls help on this.....

Many thanks....

Comment: Primary key should be set to identity = true, seed = 1

Comment: where do i have set these ones...

Comment: In properties of the column in the database. http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_s2jU7girbyM/TQrbPX_T7EI/AAAAAAAAC6Q/f_1OuWD5fHE/s1600/SQL_2008_Unable_To_Change_Id_Spec.PNG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because the product you are trying to update is already loaded by entity framework. You are creating a new instance of `product` and assigning an exisiting `product id`.

You can use the [Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) property of the `dbcontext.products` DbSet to retrieve the existing product.

```
 int updateproductid = Convert.ToInt32(datagridview1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);

 string productcategories =cbCategorytypes.Text;

 var categorytypes = (from producttype in dbcontext.categories
                      where producttype.name.Equals(productcategories)
                      select producttype.categoryId).SingleOrDefault();

 product product1 = dbcontext.products.Local.Where(p => p.productId == updateproductid).First();
 product1.Name = txtProductname.Text;
 product1.Description = txtProductdescription.Text;
 product1.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtProductPrice.Text);
 product1.categoryId = categorytypes;
 dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

You should consider using proper naming conventions

Answer (score 1):

This lines

```
product product1 = new product() { productId = updateproductid };
dbcontext.products.Attach(product1);
```

tells me that you are creating a new product and attaching it to the context. But this product already exists. You should retrieve the product based on the `updateproductid` and set the new `categoryId` or the properties that you wanna change.

More exactly you should replace

```
product product1 = new product() { productId = updateproductid };
dbcontext.products.Attach(product1);
```

with something like this

```
product product1 = (from product in dbcontext.products 
                    where productId == updateproductid select product);
```

Comment: @eranga After that  can i attach like this...product1.Name = txtProductname.Text; 
 product1.Description = txtProductdescription.Text; 
 product1.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtProductPrice.Text); 
 product1.categoryId = categorytypes; 
 dbcontext.SaveChanges();

Comment: @user844360 when you attach an entity EF checks whether it already has a copy of the entity with the same primary key because EF keeps only one copy of the entity. If the entity is loaded attaching will fail.